# gradle-maven-plugin fails to determine java 11

Tags: java, maven, gradle, java-11

Failed to execute goal org.fortasoft:gradle-maven-plugin:1.0.8:invoke (default-cli) on project server: Execution default-cli of goal org.fortasoft:gradle-maven-plugin:1.0.8:invoke failed: Could not determine java version from '11.0.2'.

Comment: This plugin is just a little bit old so I doubt that it will work on JDK9+ last release from 2015 ...? apart from that why would you like to execute gradle task within a Maven build?

Answer (score 0):

Change your maven repo address use aliyun or huawei yun, here is a link that show the required change the file "/etc/maven/settings.xml"
https://laptrinhx.com/maven-replacement-central-warehouse-aliyun-2549426160/

[Source](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/2343)